# How to Implement a TextWatcher in a DialogFragment

Tags: kotlin, android-dialogfragment, textwatcher

In my application I am creating a searchable list inside of a Dialog fragment. At the top is my editText with a TextWatcher applied to it.

However, when the TextWatcher is connected to the EditText from within onCreateDialog, I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: search_box must not be null". When this is instead placed inside onViewCreated, onViewCreated is never even called.

Can somebody explain what I am missing? Many thanks in advance

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val layoutInflater = activity.layoutInflater
    val mainView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_p, null)
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    builder.setView(mainView)

    val layout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.results_layout) as LinearLayout
    var line = 0

    for(i in nameList){
        createButton(line,layout)
        line++
    }

    //Below line: java.lang.IllegalStateException: search_box must not be null
    search_box.afterTextChanged {
        val search = search_box.text.toString().toLowerCase()
        line = 0
        layout.removeAllViews()
        for(i in nameList){
            if(contains(search,nameList[line].toLowerCase())){
                createButton(line,layout)
            }
            line++
        }
    }

    return builder.create()
}

private fun EditText.afterTextChanged(afterTextChanged: (String)-> Unit) {
    this.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0:CharSequence?,p1:Int,p2:Int,p3:Int) { }
        override fun onTextChanged(p0:CharSequence?,p1:Int,p2:Int,p3:Int) {  }
        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?){
            afterTextChanged.invoke(editable.toString())
        }
    }) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems your `Edittext` is null.

make sure your `Edittext` is not null

```
val search_box = mainView.findViewById(R.id.youredittext) as EditText


search_box.afterTextChanged {
   // do whatever
}
```